# When Google will shows the OAuth screen for Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am developing an application which uploaded the file on google drive folder. I am successfully able to do this task, to achieve this functionality I have been using the Google Drive API V3 SDK in c# web API.

As I have read the documentation I know that google will ask for the drive permission after permission drive provide us detail JSON like below:

```html
{"access_token":"","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"refresh_token":"","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","Issued":"2022-03-11T18:23:47.227+05:30","IssuedUtc":"2022-03-11T12:53:47.227Z"}
```

As you can see above there is an "expires_in" in the JSON data So I wanted to know that when I will be next prompt by google for OAuth consent screen.

How can I bypass or skip the google OAuth consent screen in my web API programmatically because I do not want my users so show that OAuth screen.

Comment: Is this an application or a web site?  A web site should automatically redirect to the Google oauth pages, for an application, you will have to implement that functionality yourself.   Expires_in:3599 is probably in seconds, so just under 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are doing. If this is the users google drive account you are connecting to.  VIA your web application Most of this is handled intenrally by the .net client libary

> {"access_token":"","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"refresh_token":"","scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive","Issued":"2022-03-11T18:23:47.227+05:30","IssuedUtc":"2022-03-11T12:53:47.227Z"}

Yes the access token expires in an hour, but assuming that you have requested offline access then you should have a refresh token. Refresh tokens are used to request a new access token when ever your access token expires.  So assuming the refresh token is still working and was not revoked your user should not be requested to authorize the application again.   Again all of this is handled internally by the [google .net client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3).

Note: If your app is still in the testing phase then the refresh token will expire after seven days. Once your application has been set to production in google developer console then the refresh tokens will no longer expire.

## auth with no consent screen

If you are accessing the users google drive account then you will always need to show them a consent screen. They need to consent to your application accessing their google drive account.

However if you are accessing a standard drive account that you the developer control.  If this is your drive account and not the users. Then you can use something called a service account.  You can share a directory on your personal drive account with the service account and then the service account will be able to access it without a consent screen needed as it was preauthorized.

[Google drive api with a service account.](https://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/)